# Could not find value of VARIABLE from The Puppet Template

Tags: templates, puppet

I'm having trouble to get Variable from the Puppet template.

es_deploy.pp class

```
class elasticsearch::es_deploy inherits elasticsearch {

    $cluster_name = 'cluster'
    notify { "Cluster_Name Value: $cluster_name": }

    $keys_cluster = keys($elasticsearch)
    deploy_on_host { $keys_cluster: es => $elasticsearch; }

    define deploy_on_host ($es) {

    $keys_node = keys($es[$title])

    deploy_instances { $keys_node: node_info => $es[$title], es_hosts => $es['node_list']; }

    define deploy_instances ($node_info, $es_hosts) {

     file {"/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml": 
       ensure => file,             
        mode => 644,
        owner => root,
        group => root,
        content  => template("elasticsearch/elasticsearch.erb");
     }

     $network_host = $node_info['ip_address']
     notify { "Network_Host Value: $network_host": }

   }
}
```

Template elasticsearch.erb

```
cluster.name: <%= scope.lookupvar("elasticsearch::es_deploy::cluster_name") -%> 
network.host: <%= @network_host %>
```

I don't know why I'm not able to get values from es_deploy class directly. I used a workaround by scope.lookupvar() to get cluster_name but it's not working with network_host in the same way. The elasticsearch template was included from define block where I set network_host variable so it should be accessible but it's not. Notify show correct both values.

Puppet shows an error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template elasticsearch/elasticsearch.erb:
Filepath: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb
Line: 82
Detail: Could not find value for 'network_host' at /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/elasticsearch/templates/elasticsearch.erb:74
at /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/elasticsearch/manifests/es_deploy.pp:123 on node es1
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `<%= @network_host %>`. You may want to read the documentation on using ERB with Puppet for more info.

Comment: Thanks Matt but it's not the problem, of course I used `<%= @network_host %>`, maybe there is a similar simple mistake but at this moment I can't find it.

Comment: You may also be messing something up by using class inheritance. Class inheritance has been highly discouraged by Puppet for a few years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is unable to directly access the variables of class `elasticsearch::es_deploy` because it is not being invoked in that class's scope.  Instead, it is being invoked in the scope of defined type `elasticsearch::es_deploy::deploy_instances`, which is unrelated to the scope of `elasticsearch::es_deploy`, naming and lexical nesting notwithstanding.

The Puppet Language Reference contains [a section on scoping rules](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/lang_scope.html), which explains this.  Since Puppet 3.0, all variable references are (supposed to be) looked up according to the *static* scoping rules, though there was at one time a bug in that regard with respect to references from templates.  Relevant provisions from the reference include (emphasis in the original):

> Code inside a class definition or defined type exists in a **local scope**.
>
> Variables and defaults declared in a local scope are only available in **that scope and its children**.

[...]

> [Version 3] of Puppet uses static scope for variables

[...]

> In **static scope**, parent scopes are **only** assigned by class inheritance (using the `inherits` keyword). Any **derived** class receives the contents of its base class in addition to the contents of node and top scope.
>
> **All other** local scopes have no parents — they only receive their own contents, and the contents of node scope (if applicable) and top scope.

If you want the template to be able to retrieve data via the expression `@cluster_name` when invoked from a defined-type instance, that needs to correspond to a local variable of that type.  You could achieve that by passing it as a parameter, or just by making a local copy of the class's variable:

```
$cluster_name = $elasticsearch::es_deploy::cluster_name
```

My suggestion, however, would be to continue having the template look up the variable in the appropriate scope if that scope indeed can be viewed as a canonical source for the information.

---

I should say also that nesting class or defined type definitions inside class bodies has widely been considered poor form since well before the release of Puppet 3.  Even in Puppet 2 and earlier, with their exclusive reliance on dynamic scope, lexically nesting definitions produced scope confusion.  The Puppet 3 (and 4) docs specifically note that the practice is *not* deprecated in that version, but warn that it is a candidate for future deprecation.  Also, [they explicitly say](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/lang_defined_types.html#location):

> Defined resource types can (and should) be stored in modules. Puppet
>   is automatically aware of any defined types in a valid module and can
>   autoload them by name.
>
> Definitions should be stored in the `manifests/` directory of a module
>   with one definition per file, and each filename should reflect the
>   name of its defined type.

I should be clear that in context, it is evident that the docs are distinguishing "should" from "must" in those comments.

Comment: Definitely seems to be the solution here and written up very well.

Comment: Thanks John, You did a great job!